# adding fields (inputs) to images

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

im using dropzone to upload multiple images, and works fine, untill i want to insert a brand and url to each image.

The only issue im having is when im going to get the values from the input fields, im getting in myt request from the server undefined values from the fieds (brand, url) but if im using static text it appears no problem.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#add').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

   Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    // Dropzone class:
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", {
        url: "/galleries",
        autoProcessQueue:false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'vjghjghjhgjghjghjghjgLxX',

        },
        params: {
            'brand': $('#brand').val(),
            'url' : $('#url').val(),
            'description': 'small detail'
        },
        previewTemplate: "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\">\n  " +
        "<div class=\"dz-image\"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>\n " +
        "<input type=\"text\" id=\"brand\" name=\"dz-brand\">\n " +
                "<input type=\"text\" id=\"url\" name=\"dz-url\">\n 
..../div>"
             }



   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT: Updated all of this answer:

Your Ids are not unique, therefore you can't reliably get the input data from the ID selector.

Change your IDs on your inputs in the template to classes like this:

```
previewTemplate: "<div class='dz-preview dz-file-preview'>\n  " +
    "<div class='dz-image'><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>\n " +
    "<input type='text' class='dz-brand' value='This is the text'> \n " +
    "<input type='text' class='dz-url'>\n </div>"
```

Then add the parameters with the sending event, this will get the input values at the time of upload.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('brand'      , $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-brand').val());
    formData.append('url'        , $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-url').val());
    formData.append('description', 'small detail');
});
```

Refer to the Documentation here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending

Comment: This is what i did, 'formData.append('brand'      : $('#brand').val());' or better, the right way is formData.append('brand' ,$('#brand').val());... Is with a comma, but doesnt work, all images gets the first title or information of the first image

Comment: one question, why isnt the form validations tags "required" arent working?

Comment: That's a different question. Ask a new question and mark this one as accepted if it fixes your problem. I'd need to see how you are making the form to try to replicate the problem